# Questions on the use of tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, embedding

I have some questions on the use of the embedding columns implemented in tensorflow in tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column.

I'm training a binary classifier for a two player game (tennis, in this case). My features that I pass to the DNNClassifier as feature_columns look as follows:

```
deep_columns = [
tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(player1, dimension=9),
tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(player2, dimension=9),
tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(court, dimension=1),
tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(surface, dimension=1),
p1Rank, p2Rank]
```

What I'm wondering about is this: am I now learning two different embeddings for the same set of players? And if so, is there a way to use one embedding layer for both players? Or is there nothing wrong with doing it the way I'm currently doing it?

A second question regarding the embedding_column: the docs mention this, as possible arguments for embedding_column:

```
ckpt_to_load_from: (Optional). String representing checkpoint name/pattern to restore the column weights. Required if tensor_name_in_ckpt is not None.
tensor_name_in_ckpt: (Optional). Name of the Tensor in the provided checkpoint from which to restore the column weights. Required if ckpt_to_load_from is not None.
```

Does this imply that if none of these is provided, the embedding layers are initialized randomly again when restoring my model from a checkpoint?

And then one final question: The two embedding columns for `court` and `surface` have a dimension of 1, as they only have very few options. Is this a bad use of an embedding column? Or is it okay to use it like that?

Thanks in advance!